# PHP Image Type Validation

Tags: php, image, post, strcmp

i am trying to match a `image/type` of a file upload in `PHP` for validation:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
  $data = [
        // Other POST Variables
     'uploadimageType' => $_FILES['uploadimage']['type']
  ];
  if((strcmp($data['uploadimageType'],'image/jpeg')!=0) || (strcmp($data['uploadimageType'],'image/png')!=0) || (strcmp($data['uploadimageType'],'image/gif')!=0) ) {
     echo 'Invalid Image format';
  }else{
     echo 'Valid';
  } 
?>
```

The HTML used for submit:

```
<form action="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/users/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!-- Other Input Tags -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="uploadimage">Upload Image <sup>*</sup></label>
    <input type="file" name="uploadimage" class="form-control-file <?php echo (!empty($data['uploadimage_err'])) ?  'is-invalid' : ''; ?>">
    <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $data['uploadimage_err']; ?></span>
  </div>
  <!-- Submit Button -->
</form>
```

Now, the problem is that even if I try to upload an image(.jpg, .png, .gif) it shows **Invalid Image Format**. Is there anything that I am missing here because this seems to be very simple yet complicated. Any suggestions would help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$allowed_mime_type_arr = array('image/gif','image/jpeg','image/pjpeg','image/png','image/x-png');
$mime = get_mime_by_extension($_FILES['uploadimage']['name']);
if(in_array($mime, $allowed_mime_type_arr)){
   echo 'Valid Image format';
}else{ 
   echo 'Invalid Image format';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will Works by Change if Condition.

```
  $data = [
    'uploadimageType' => 'image/jpeg'
  ];
  if((strcmp($data['uploadimageType'],'image/jpeg')!=0) && (strcmp($data['uploadimageType'],'image/png')!=0) && (strcmp($data['uploadimageType'],'image/gif')!=0) ) {    
            echo 'Invalid Image format';
   }
   else {
       echo 'Valid';
   }
```

Comment: I just wanted to know why it won't work like the way I wrote it

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
  $data = ['uploadimageType' => strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['uploadimage']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION))];
  $ext = array("png","jpg","jpeg");
  if(!in_array($data['uploadimageType'],$ext) ) {
    echo 'Invalid Image format';
  }else {
    echo 'Valid';
  }    
}
```